# Checkboxes mysql conditions confusing :(

Tags: mysql, checkbox

i'm trying to make a search filter with checkboxes but the mysql OR and AND conditions are very confusing. How do i set it to display all the results that are checked by the user? Here is my code.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$DB_HOST = "localhost"; 
$DB_NAME = "mysite"; 
$DB_USER = "root"; 
$DB_PASS = "***"; // password edited out

$conn = new mysqli($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME);
if($conn->connect_errno > 0) {
  die('Connection failed [' . $conn->connect_error . ']');
}




$sql="SELECT * FROM websiteusers ";
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $searchgender = isset($_POST['gender'])  ? mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['gender']) : '';

    $searchethnicity = isset($_POST['ethnicity'])  ? mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['ethnicity']) : '';

    $sql .= "WHERE gender = '{$searchgender}'";
    $sql .= " OR ethnicity = '{$searchethnicity}' ";
}

$query=mysqli_query($conn,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));


?>

<?php
$query=mysqli_query($conn,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
?>

<form name="form" action="" method="post">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Gender:
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="gender" value="male">Male<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="gender" value="female">Female
        </td>
    </tr>
    //more code (it says too much code lol)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
    $sql .= "WHERE gender = '{$searchgender}'";

   // if Gender checkbox check then add or ohter wise normal condition
   if(!empty($searchgender)){

     $sql .= " OR ";
   }
    $sql .= " ethnicity = '{$searchethnicity}' ";
```

Comment: could you please elaborate what you did?

Answer (score 0):

```
//try this
$sql="SELECT * FROM websiteusers where 1 AND ";
$searchgender = trim($_POST['gender']);
$searchethnicity = trim($_POST['searchethnicity']);
if($searchgender!='')
{
 $sql .= " gender = '".$searchgender."'";
 }
 if($searchgender!='' && $searchethnicity!='')
 $sql .=" OR ";

if($searchethnicity!='')
 $sql .= " ethnicity = '".searchethnicity."'";
```

Comment: i dont understand what you did. Also, should there be curly braces in the if statements?

Comment: @babyleans do not need of curly braces for single line statement,we checked both value exist then OR include Otherwise gender or city search by default in case of one value select.